# How to keep secondary monitor display open when using Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, windows-10

I am using Lightroom 6.0 on Windows 10. I'd like to be able to work in another program and keep the secondary monitor display on.

Right now, when Lightroom is the active program, the secondary display stays on, but when I switch to another program (for example by clicking its icon in the task bar) the secondary display goes off and then turns on when I click on Lightroom again.

Is it possible to keep the secondary display always on?